# Is there a way in Tkinter to create a pop up message?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create pop up messages like this in Tkinter. Is there a way to do it?[image: Wordle Message Pop Up]

I do not want a message pop up that requires the user to press a button or to react to disappear or messagebox module or a Toplevel object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with a TopLevel that expires after a period of time, such as 2 seconds?

Comment: That is a good idea... However, I would prefer to have a pop up that is minimal like the one in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the popup is fully within the window, you can simply place a `Label` where you want the popup to show up and schedule a call to destroy it after some delay:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def show_popup():
    label = tk.Label(root, text="This is a popup message!", bg="black", fg="white", wraplength=100)
    label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
    root.after(2000, label.destroy)

tk.Label(root, text="Some text here.").pack(padx=10, pady=10)
tk.Button(root, text="Show popup", command=show_popup).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```